# "ifup eth0" causes dhclient to bring up more than one interface

Tags: networking, debian, isc-dhcp, dhclient

Can someone tell me why dhclient is not respecting to only handle the one interface it has been passed?

I've seen this multiple times over the years; never figured it out - it's not related to wpa_applicant, my interfaces are pretty standard (see below)... this is what I see:

```
root@zincshark:/etc/network# ifup eth1
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/10:fe:ed:21:c9:ca
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/10:fe:ed:21:c9:ca
Listening on LPF/eth1/00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Sending on   LPF/eth1/00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
....
```

This is the relevant part of my interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_telekom.conf

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

I noticed that `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.*.leases` contains bad leases - i.e. the lease file for wlan0 contains leases for eth0, I thought that was a problem so I wrote a cleanup script which I hooked into all `/etc/network/if-*.d/` parts - but it did not help.

I debugged a bit - turns out dhclient is only called once; so this is a problem in dhclient - not in the debian networking subsystem...

Comment: I just saw [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/172406/linux-sbin-dhclient-to-bind-to-a-specific-interface?rq=1) - I'm not sure if this is related - my question isn't about the dhclients running as daemons; just the explicit call (in which case - according to the documentation - it should ignore the other interfaces?)

Comment: Furthermore it does not look as dhclient attempts to up _all_ interfaces - I see pretty strange behaviour... `ifup eth1` brings up eth1 and wlan0 - `ifup wlan0` OTOH only brings up wlan0 and not eth1...

Comment: I have the same question in 2023: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742153/dhclient-process-messes-up-the-wrong-interface. Have you found any solution to this after all these years?

Comment: I think I found the solution, to future readers: please see the answer to my question, in short: check dhclient.conf for `interface "name" { ... }` sections.